# drawing ellipse in gnuplot using major axis, minor axis

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I am trying to draw a simple ellipse using gnuplot, but everywhere I read, one need data points to plot the ellipse.

Is there a comand in gnuplot where an ellipse is drawn simply by inputting semi major, semi minor, center of ellipse, and angle?

something like an one liner.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in [parametric mode](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/param.html):

```
a = 5.
b = 2.
set parametric
plot [0:2*pi] a*cos(t), b*sin(t)
```

[image]

Comment: i found the answer.. see below... was looking for some oneliner.

Answer (score 1):

This did the job

center is center; size is major, minor and angle is angle..

```
set object 1 ellipse center 1.5, 1  size 6, 12  angle 60 front fs empty bo 3
plot '-' with points
```

Of course, one needs to do the usual task, such as setting the ranges, terminal etc. beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gnuplot from a bash shell you can do:

```
plot "<( echo x y a b angle )" w ellipses
```

Example:

```
plot "<( echo 0 0 2 1 45 )" w ellipses
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, in addition to @emmanuel's answer which uses a system call and works for gnuplot>=5.0.

Here is a solution without system call which works also for gnuplot>=4.6.0 (March 2012). The special filename `'+'` is used. The option `every ::::0` is used to plot only a single ellipse.

```
plot '+' u (0):(0):(2):(1):(45) every ::::0 w ellipses
```

If you need to plot multiple different ellipses you can put your parameters into a file or datablock.

[image]